# useLocation working in GoogleChrome but not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, location

I'm developing a web site, and I'm using the React Router API.
I'm trying to pass objects as state in `history.push()`

Here are my components :

**HeaderNav.js**

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

function HeaderNav({ source, id }) {

  const history = useHistory();

  function handleButton(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    history.push({
      pathname: `articles/${id}`,
      state: {article: source}
    })
  }
  return (
    <div className="article-header-nav">
      <h3>{source.title}</h3>
      <button onClick={handleButton} className="button-primary">Go</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

My component that is rendered when hitting /articles/:id :

**ArticleDetail.js**

```
function ArticleDetail() {
  const location = useLocation();
  console.log(location.state.article);

  function renderArticle(){
   /*
     DOES STUFF WITH location.state.article to render the article on page
   */
  }
  return (
   <div>
     {renderArticle()}
   </div>
  )

}
```

This is perfectly working in **GoogleChrome** but not in **Firefox**... why is that ?

Thanks for your answers :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found the problem

I create my history like this :  `const history = createBrowserHistory({ forceRefresh: true });` and on refresh the state passed via `history.push()` is lost... But I still do not understand why it works on Chrome and not Firefox

Comment: I am seeing the same issue in my app. Did you ever figure out how to fix it?

Comment: Nop... I finally passed the article `id` through the URL and queried my database in `ArticleDetail.js` to fetch the article instead of passing it through the state...

Answer (score 0):

The `Location.reload()` method reloads the current URL, like the Refresh button.

The reload may be blocked and a **SECURITY_ERROR DOMException** thrown. This happens if the origin of the script calling location.reload() differs from the origin of the page that owns the Location object. See Same-origin policy for more information.

If that doesn't solve it, see if this causes the issue please.
A browser without the Redux DevTools Extension may produce an error if the Redux store is not properly created. It may happen that the error still produces even though the extension is not working in the browser for some kind of error installation. So if the extension is not working make sure too uninstall it.

To fix the error on browsers without the extension, create the Redux store with `window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__` instead of `window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__`

Does this answer your question?

------------------+-----------------------+---------------------------------+-------------

To install the redux-devtools-extension npm package you can use:

```
npm install --save-dev redux-devtools-extension
```

But for production builds you may need instead:

```
npm install redux-devtools-extension
```

Comment: I am not using redux in my app, the thing is that on Firefox my state stays undefined but not on Chrome :/